# Use excel file variables in SOAP request in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I've faced with a problem. I'm new in SoapUI.
I must read excel file and then put some variables in the soap request. This is what I've done:
I've add a groovy script to get the excel file data:
import jxl.*

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\PATH\\TestData.xls"))
Sheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1")
def rows = sheet1.getRows()
def cols = sheet1.getColumns()
log.info "Row Count =" + rows 
log.info "Column Count =" + cols 
def array = []
for(i=1;i<rows;i++) { 
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++) { 
       Cell cell = sheet1.getCell(j,i)
       def variable = cell.getContents()
       log.info cell.getContents() 
       array << variable
    } 
}
return array
```

array returns: 10 and 20.
And this is a soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:intA>10</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>10</tem:intB>
      </tem:Add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can I somehow call a groovy script and put variables in

```
             <tem:intA>10</tem:intA>
             <tem:intB>20</tem:intB>
```

Instead of 10 and 20, I should call a groovy script method and put data, which I've taken from excel file.

Comment: Is there always going to be exactly two variables: intA and intB? Or does this need to be more dynamic?

Comment: yes, its going to be intA and intB always in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your use-case is trivial: just two variables to be substituted, you can just use two properties.

Change the `return array` in your script to something like:

```
testCase.setPropertyValue("intA", array[0].toString())
testCase.setPropertyValue("intB", array[1].toString())
```

And then your request to:

```
     <tem:intA>${#TestCase#intA}</tem:intA>
     <tem:intB>${#TestCase#intB}</tem:intB>
```